# Alternative to logically orphaned objects

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently designing an API which is very hierarchical in nature, in that most object types are parented by a container object of another type. For example:

```
interface Parent {
    Set<Child> getChildren();

    Child createChild();
}

interface Child {
    Parent getParent();

    // other methods
}
```

This design becomes a bit problematic, however, when a method such as `removeChild` is added to `Parent`. When called, the child is dissociated from the parent, effectively orphaning it and rendering it obsolete.

However, a program using the API may retain references to the `Child`, and so to ensure that no methods are erroneously called, the current design sees that all methods defined by `Child` will throw an `OrphanedObjectException` (which extends `IllegalStateException`) if the target is orphaned.

I'm not confident this is the best solution, so I'd like to know if there's a better or more OO approach to this issue.

Comment: You should not try to control everything! Logically, in the life there are orphans, and they are not meant to be destroyed. I do not know if it is possible at the level of your API to control what users of your API are doing with the objects they created from your API class. If you want to do that, you are about to create your own virtual machine like JVM.

Comment: I can control (limit) what users are doing with the object via the aforementioned `OrphanedObjectException`, but I'm looking for a cleaner route than this.

Comment: I got the point that you can control via `OrphanedObjectException`. What I was saying is that if you need that type of control, there is possibly something wrong in your design.

Comment: I recognize that it's not exactly an elegant solution, but I'm not even sure of what basic design changes would be necessary to avoid the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a question of "hierarchy" so much as effective cleanup. If the child should cease to exist when it is removed from its parent, then you need to make sure it ceases to exist. Remove every reference to it that's being held by other parts of the API.

One way you might do this is by making something like a `ChildManager` that class keeps track of every object that needs to be asked to throw away its reference to the child, and a `ChildConsumer` interface that is implemented by every class that uses a `Child`. Something like:

```
class ChildManager {
   private Child child = null;

   public void register(Child child);
   public void unregister(Child child);
   public Child consume(ChildConsumer consumer);
}

interface ChildConsumer { 
    public void releaseChild(Child child);
}
```

Now a `Parent` holds a `ChildManager`. Every time it gains a child, it calls `register`. Every time another object needs access to one of those children, it calls `consume`, and it must implement `releaseChild` so that it will no longer have a reference to that child after it is consumed. Now `Parent` is responsible for calling `unregister` during `remove`, and `unregister` calls `releaseChild` for every consumer, ensuring that the `Child` is completely removed.

In some sense it feels like you're re-implementing reference counting, but it's better to design a system where `OrphanedObjectException` isn't hiding beneath every one of your method calls, in my opinion.

Another solution might be to pass out a [`WeakReference<Child>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to every object that holds a possibly-orphaned `Child` and check for `null` every time you call `get`. This saves you from `OrphanedObjectException`. This seems more natural and Java-ish, but creates a lot of ugly checks for `null` scattered through your code.

Comment: The issue with this is that while the implementation is currently handling children responsibly, there's no way to ensure third-party programs utilizing the API are without requiring them to implement `ChildConsumer` where applicable. Furthermore, there's no clean way to enforce this, complicating usage of the API more than is necessary in my opinion due to this requirement being less-than-obvious.

Comment: @caseif Ah, I see, I assumed that you wanted to enforce this only for your code, not for external code. In that case, I think your only option is to pass out `WeakReference<Child>` objects instead of `Child` objects throughout your code, and only give your user a strong reference to `Parent`. That's extremely awkward, though, and I don't think you gain enough to justify moving away from your current solution.

Comment: Furthermore, the API is built in part on the principle of `Optional`s, meaning the return type would look something like `Optional<WeakReference<Child>>`.

Comment: @caseif I think it's another strike against the use of `WeakReference` if you've designed your API in such a way that you avoid `null` everywhere. I don't think you can do much better than your `OrphanedObjectException` without introducing some weird proxy object, either `WeakReference` or your own, hand-rolled one that will return an `Optional<Child>`.